# Htaccess 301 redirect issue, previous link remains in URL bar with tag attached

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**Edit** Yes, It is a stupid question, but I can't find a solution in enough time that pertains to the problem.

I'm trying to create some redirect links since I updated my website, as the old ones are no longer in use. I have my .htaccess file set up as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Permanent URL redirect - generated by www.rapidtables.com
Redirect 301 /posts/content/2/building-your-own-mvc-framework-in-php-part-1 https://ciangallagher.net/#post2
```

Which works, however it leaves a `?url=` tag in the URL bar with the original redirected link as so:

[image]

How can I amend my .htaccess file to remove this tag and just reidrect to the desired link which would be `https://ciangallagher.net/post2`?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this, the issue was that the `RewriteRule` I had already set was interfering with the redirects.